# Parsing json response gives undefined

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using angularfire2 to fetch data from realtime DB. and response comes like below

```
    {"type":"value",
     "payload":{
                   "-LJXFAd_q3Cin64EBc7H":
                     {"_date":"9-8-2018",
                      "_deliveryType":"Pick up",
                      "_estDeliveryTime":"2018-08-10T11:43:57.164Z",
                       "_location":""}
}}
```

this on doing

the element inside payload is a key created using push. I wont know it to refer so how do i get the data under "LJXFAd_q3Cin64EBc7H" ?

there are many such entries inside payload and i need to fetch all.

code used to get above is:

```
getOrderHistory(uid:string){
    console.log('start of getOrderHistory with uid:' + uid)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      {
        this.db.object("/users/" + uid + "/orders").snapshotChanges().subscribe(
          res => {
            //console.log('response:' + res)
            resolve(res)
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
          }
        )
      })
  }
```

Comment: Could you show us what you're doing to get that response?

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it maps each snapshot to an object that holds its key and values.

```js
this.db.object("/users/" + uid + "/orders").snapshotChanges()
.map(snapshot => {
  const key = snapshot.key;
  const data = snapshot.payload.val();
  return { key, ...data };
})
.subscribe(res => {
  resolve(res);
},
err => {
  console.log(err);
  reject(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

normally, realtime database sends snapshot where you can do snapshot.id to get the id and .data (or .data() I forget at the moment) to get at the payload.

`JSON.parse` it then iterate it or get at it with dot notation or bracket notation. To get a property:

```
obj[payload][LJXFAd_q3Cin64EBc7H]
```

To iterate it:

```
function eachRecursive(obj)
{
    for (var k in obj)
    {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null)
            eachRecursive(obj[k]);
        else
            // do something... 
    }
}
```

Comment: LJXFAd_q3Cin64EBc7H is coming from server. i wont know it so cannot refer as u did. it wont be known to me

Comment: normally, realtime database sends `snapshot` where you can do `snapshot.id` to get the id and `.data` (or `.data()` I forget at the moment) to get at the payload.